# Leibniz Formula for Pi using Python

Tags: python, lua

I'm trying to recreate a program I made in  Lua. I've been trying to translate it to Python (3.5.0)

The program is meant to allow the user to input a certain number of iterations and then the program goes through them and displays the value of pi.

[image]

So let's say the user inputs the iteration of 1, the program goes through the formula (in the picture) and does the math. The first iterations would be pi = 4/1 which would make the value of pi = 4. Here's a list of a few iterations and their values of pi: [List of Iterations and Pi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZd2K.jpg).

Also, if you would like to see my code using Lua here are two links [Simple Pi Estimation Program](http://pastebin.com/usDAi4pu) and I have another more complex one, but it wouldn't work in Python. Another example, if the user inputs the iteration of 5 the program would calculate the value of pi to be 3.339.

AND as I said I've attempted to make it in Python, but I just can't do it. Any suggestions would be appreciative. Here is what I have written (it is most defintetly wrong):

```
def estimate_pi( iterations, pi = 0 ):
    print("How many iterations?")
    iterations = input()
    sign = -1.0
    for n in range(iterations):
        sign = sign*-1 # alternate sign as 1 or -1
        pi = pi+4/(n*2-1)*sign # multiply by sign for a + or - answer
        print("Pi: ", pi) #print value of Pi
    return;
```

Comment: The formula is http://imgur.com/9dcPQfP here

Comment: Are you *sure* you're running in Python 3.5.0?  That code shouldn't work in 3.5.  [That's not the problem with your code, but `input` returns a string in 3.5, and so `range(iterations)` shouldn't work.]

Comment: But be aware that Leibniz's formula converges extremely slowly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_pi#Convergence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is not *that* wrong. You are missing that python's range goes `0..n-1`. Fixed and improved:

```
def estimate_pi( iterations ):
    sign,pi = 1,0.0
    for n in range(iterations):
        pi += 4/(n*2+1)*sign # multiply by sign for a + or - answer
        # --- prev line's formula has +1 instead of -1
        sign *= -1 # alternate sign as 1 or -1
    return pi

print("How many iterations?")
print(estimate_pi(int(input())))
```

Comment: I think you missed the `0..n-1` part as well :) would it not be `range(0, iterations+1)` with the same sign as the OP?

Comment: Hege, when I use that code the iteration of 1 works fine, but the others do not. I inputted 2 and it gives me 5.33... but it should give me 2.66...which is half of 5.33...

Comment: You made type in `sign *= 1`. It should work correctly with `sign *= -1`

Comment: Changing sign *= 1 to sign *= -1 now does the next iteration. When I input 0 it shows 4.0 (which should be the iteration of 1). When I type in 1 it shows 2.66 (which should be the iteration of 2) and so on

Comment: both of you are right, I made a mistake by not running the program

Comment: I have edited my answer so it gives correct results now.

Comment: Strange...I'm using your edited code, but it still shows the incorrect value of pi. I keep on getting the _next_ value

Comment: @Coding4Days Right, it's a shame I couldn't get this straight even for third trial. Take a look at now please.